# How do i properly load an attribute from a tag from XML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing

```xml
    <config>
            <maps>
        <map name="2042" xml="2042.xml" preview="2042.jpg"/>
        <map name="2042 (Snow)" xml="2042Z.xml" preview="2042Z.jpg"/>
        <map name="2008 Tanks" xml="2008tanks.xml" preview="2008tanks.jpg"/>
        <map name="Abyss" xml="besdna.xml" preview="besdna.jpg"/>
            </maps>
        <numerics>
            <numeric name="Repair Kit" url="data/numerics/heal.png" price="112"/>
            <numeric name="Double Armor" url="data/numerics/armor.png" price="37"/>
            <numeric name="Double Damage" url="data/numerics/damage.png" price="37"/>
            <numeric name="Speed Boost" url="data/numerics/n2o.png" price="37"/>
            <numeric name="Mine" url="data/numerics/mine.png" price="37"/>
        </numerics>
        <descriptions>
            <turrets>
                <description name="Smoky" text="data/turrets/smoky/m0/preview.png;Medium"/>
                <description name="Ricochet Prototype" text="data/turrets/striker/m0/preview.png;This"/>
                <description name="Smoky XT" text="data/turrets/gauss/prime/preview.png;A special"/>
                <description name="Railgun Prototype" text="data/turrets/railgun/prime/preview.png;One"/>
            </turrets>
            <numerics>
                <description name="Repair Kit" text='data/numerics/hea.png;Gradually'/>
                <description name="Double Armor" text='data/numerics/armo.png;Doubles'/>
                <description name="Double Damage" text='data/numerics/damag.png;Doubles'/>
                <description name="Speed Boost" text='data/numerics/n2.png;Increases'/>
                <description name="Mine" text='data/numerics/min.png;The'/>
            </numerics>
        </descriptions>
    </config>
```

This is my XML file and i'm trying to get from under  the attribute value of price from the third  tag
Here`s what i've tried :

```js
         const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1/config.xml");
         const xml = await response.text();
         const parser = new DOMParser();
         const doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");

            const configElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("config")[0];
            const numericsElement = configElement.getElementsByTagName("numeric");
            console.log('numericsElement = ' + numericsElement.length);
            const numerics = numericsElement[0];
            const numericElements = numerics.getElementsByTagName("numeric");
            console.log('numericElements = ' + numericElements.length);
            const desiredNumericElement = numericElements[2];
            const price = desiredNumericElement.getAttribute("price");
```

*The javascript code is inside an async function*

I tried the same thing with  tag and it worked to get an attribute from it , why doesnt it work with ? Also i need  from the first  tag , not the one under  tag

*Edit* : After a bit i printed the `doc` variable and realised that it only parsed the maps element from the config.xml file

Comment: `numerics` is a single `numeric` element. A `numeric` has no children. Calling `getElementsByTagName` on it will always give a zero length list. I think you made a typo and intended `configElement.getElementsByTagName("numeric")` to search for `numerics` not `numeric`

Comment: i actually debugged a bit more and realised that it only parser the <maps> tag and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selector or XPath to fetch nodes/values from the XML. So after you fetch the XML string:

```js
const dataDocument = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(getXMLString(), "application/xml");

console.log(
  dataDocument
    // css selector
    .querySelector(
      'config > numerics > numeric[name="Double Damage"]'
    )
    ?.getAttribute('price')
);

console.log(
  // xpath expression
  dataDocument.evaluate(
    'number(/config/numerics/numeric[@name="Double Damage"]/@price)',
    dataDocument,
    null,
    XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE
  ).numberValue
);

function getXMLString() {
  return `<config>
            <maps>
        <map name="2042" xml="2042.xml" preview="2042.jpg"/>
        <map name="2042 (Snow)" xml="2042Z.xml" preview="2042Z.jpg"/>
        <map name="2008 Tanks" xml="2008tanks.xml" preview="2008tanks.jpg"/>
        <map name="Abyss" xml="besdna.xml" preview="besdna.jpg"/>
            </maps>
        <numerics>
            <numeric name="Repair Kit" url="data/numerics/heal.png" price="112"/>
            <numeric name="Double Armor" url="data/numerics/armor.png" price="37"/>
            <numeric name="Double Damage" url="data/numerics/damage.png" price="37"/>
            <numeric name="Speed Boost" url="data/numerics/n2o.png" price="37"/>
            <numeric name="Mine" url="data/numerics/mine.png" price="37"/>
        </numerics>
        <descriptions>
            <turrets>
                <description name="Smoky" text="data/turrets/smoky/m0/preview.png;Medium"/>
                <description name="Ricochet Prototype" text="data/turrets/striker/m0/preview.png;This"/>
                <description name="Smoky XT" text="data/turrets/gauss/prime/preview.png;A special"/>
                <description name="Railgun Prototype" text="data/turrets/railgun/prime/preview.png;One"/>
            </turrets>
            <numerics>
                <description name="Repair Kit" text='data/numerics/hea.png;Gradually'/>
                <description name="Double Armor" text='data/numerics/armo.png;Doubles'/>
                <description name="Double Damage" text='data/numerics/damag.png;Doubles'/>
                <description name="Speed Boost" text='data/numerics/n2.png;Increases'/>
                <description name="Mine" text='data/numerics/min.png;The'/>
            </numerics>
        </descriptions>
    </config>`;
}
```

Comment: There was a syntax errror inside the xml wich was causing the parser to stop at one point and the parser stopped there ignoring whats coming next , that was causing my problem

Comment: how do i close this question?